# Using SBT 0.10.0 to generate source code with ANTLR3

Tags: code-generation, antlr3, sbt

How would I use the [simple build tool (sbt)](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) 0.10.0 to generate any kind of source code based on an ANTLR3 grammar?

I guess I have to use a plugin for something like this, if I want to use the generated code within the same project or a subproject of the same parent project. Are there any existing plugins for SBT 0.10? ...or maybe another solution without using a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need to use a plugin.

First you will need to define antlr as a dependency.  Then you will need to define your source generation task according to this page:

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Common-Tasks

Your task definition is going to look something like this:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= sourceManaged in Compile map { dir =>
  <code to generate source from grammar files>
}
```

Where the code to generate your source will create a new [`org.antlr.Tool`](http://www.antlr.org/depot/antlr3/release-3.1.3/tool/src/main/java/org/antlr/Tool.java) object with your files as an argument to the constructor.  Once you have created a `Tool` object, then invoke the `process` method, and your source should be generated.

Comment: @steffen I'm curious how this works, this was a shot in the dark based on what it took to get ANTLR working with Gradle (http://www.gradle.org/).

Comment: This is actually the way to go. Meanwhile I started a plugin which makes it somewhat more reusable. It'a available on my github page and linked in the "official" sbt plugin list https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/sbt-0.10-plugins-list. Thanks again for the pointer.